# Chain component exception adding JMS channel adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to create a chain that included the jms driven channel adapter as the first step in the chain however it throws the following exception. If I remove it from the chain it will work. Can jms channel adapters be in the chain component?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd">




    <channel id="jmsInChannel">
        <int:queue/>
    </channel>

    <beans:bean id="messageListener" class="spring.integration.mq.DemoBean" />


     <int:chain input-channel="jmsInChannel" >
            <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
            destination="requestQueue" 
            error-channel="errorChannel" />

            <int:service-activator 
            ref="messageListener" method="upperCase"/>

        <int:splitter/>

        <jms:outbound-channel-adapter 
            id="outboundChannel"
            destination="outbound" 
            message-converter="oxmMessageConverter">
    </jms:outbound-channel-adapter>

     </int:chain>
</beans:beans>
```

**Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.util.List] for property 'handlers'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint] to required type [org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler] for property 'handlers[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:172)
    at spring.integration.mq.Main_MQGateway.main(Main_MQGateway.java:53)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [java.util.List] for property 'handlers'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint] to required type [org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler] for property 'handlers[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:603)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint] to required type [org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler] for property 'handlers[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedCollection(TypeConverterDelegate.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:576)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it can't: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3023.
Pay attention to the discussion by the Reference URL link.

The `<chain>` represents a `Consumer` component to accept the message and process it.

To be honest, we don't want to do any XML-specific hard work any more. The world has moved to the Java & Annotation configuration with the Spring Boot era.

The [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl) fills the gap with that `<chain>` problem.

Comment: Ya i'm running on java 6, WAS 7. Still mostly xml.  Haven't made the jump yet to spring boot that recommends Java 8.